# "NullReferenceException" in Unity3D when trying deserialize data from JSON

Tags: c#, json, parsing, unity-game-engine

I need to get some data from json file i've got it to the string named dataAsJson, on debugging it looks like that:

```
    {\r\n\t\"question\":\r\n\t[\r\n\t\t{\r\n\t\t\"text\": 
    \"głośniki\",\r\n\t\t\"correct\": \"speaker\",\r\n\t\t\"answer1\": 
    \"speaker1\",\r\n\t\t\"answer2\": \"speaker2\",\r\n\t\t\"answer3\": 
    \"speaker3\"\r\n\t\t},\r\n\t\t{\r\n\t\t\"text\": 
    \"pustynia\",\r\n\t\t\"correct\": \"desert\",\r\n\t\t\"answer1\": 
    \"desert1\",\r\n\t\t\"answer2\": \"desert2\",\r\n\t\t\"answer3\": 
    \"deser3\"\r\n\t\t},\r\n\t\t{\r\n\t\t\"text\": 
    \"rycerz\",\r\n\t\t\"correct\": \"knight\",\r\n\t\t\"answer1\": 
    \"knight1\",\r\n\t\t\"answer2\": \"knight2\",\r\n\t\t\"answer3\": 
    \"knight3\"\r\n\t\t}\r\n\t]\r\n}
```

And then i use JsonUtility.FromJson(dataAsjJson)
This is my objects classes:

```
    public class Question
    {
     public string text { get; set; }
     public string correct { get; set; }
     public string answer1 { get; set; }
     public string answer2 { get; set; }
     public string answer3 { get; set; }
    }
    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<Question> questions { get; set; }
    }
```

As you can see the json body is only the "question" with array.
On Debug.log(dataAsJson) it looks normally:

```
    {
        "question":
        [
            {
            "text": "głośniki",
            "correct": "speaker",
            "answer1": "speaker1",
            "answer2": "speaker2",
            "answer3": "speaker3"
            },
            {
            "text": "pustynia",
            "correct": "desert",
            "answer1": "desert1",
            "answer2": "desert2",
            "answer3": "deser3"
            },
            {
            "text": "rycerz",
            "correct": "knight",
            "answer1": "knight1",
            "answer2": "knight2",
            "answer3": "knight3"
            }
        ]
    }
```

I need to convert it succesfully to C# object.

Comment: Your c# models don't match the JSON.  The JSON is an object with a single property, "question", containing an array of questions.  You're trying to deserialize it as an object containing a property "questions" containing an array of questions.  Note the "s".

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Amy in the comments, your C# class structure doesn't match your JSON, I use http://json2csharp.com/ because it's accurate and quick. Make sure you put [Serializable] above each class so we can transform data structures or object states into a format that Unity can store and reconstruct later read more [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html). Lastly, I would avoid getters and setters in this structure, it will cause problems with serializing & is recommended by unity to use fields instead.

```
[Serializable]
public class Question
{
    public string text;
    public string correct;
    public string answer1;
    public string answer2;
    public string answer3;
}
[Serializable]
public class RootObject
{
    public List<Question> question;
}
```

Comment: `can cause problems` .. it **will** cause problems ;) Properties are never serialized so you should always use fields for serialized and deserialized stuff.